# update only if new id is inserted in after insert trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
 {  
 UPDATE ALL_STUDENTS a SET EMAIL = 
(SELECT email FROM STUDENTS WHERE 
locate(upper(STUDENTS_NAME),upper(a.STUDENTS_NAME)) 
and (a.INSTITUTE_NAME_1= INSTITUTE_NAME 
 or  a.INSTITUTE_NAME_2= INSTITUTE_NAME 
  or a.INSTITUTE_NAME_3=INSTITUTE_NAME 
    or a.INSTITUTE_NAME_4=INSTITUTE_NAME 
       or a.INSTITUTE_NAME_5=INSTITUTE_NAME 
          or a.INSTITUTE_NAME_5=INSTITUTE_NAME 
           and a.INSTITUTE_NAME_6=INSTITUTE_NAME)
            AND upper(DATE_OF_BIRTH)=upper(a.DATE_OF_BIRTH)  LIMIT 1 )

    }
```

THIS is my query which is supposed to be executed if any new row is inserted in STUDENTS table . BUT this query takes lot of time since it again starts from 1st id matches all the condition (which is no need bcoz their email has been updated ) .I wont to execute this query for new rows or new id inserted only

Comment: You cannot action the table which caused the trigger to fire in the trigger other than to amend NEW. values. And since when did mysql use {}?

Comment: SELECT a.STUDENTS_NAME from ALL_STUDENTS a INNER join STUDENTS b on  a.DATE_OF_BIRTH=b.DATE_OF_BIRTH  where 
locate(a.STUDENTS_NAME,b.NAME) why this query is not giving output when i have a matching birth date and students_name as 'abc' and name as 'abc xyz'

Comment: Because where locate(a.STUDENTS_NAME,b.NAME) should be where locate(B.NAME,A.STUDENTS_NAME)